# C# WPF Scrollbar changes/moves content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having a hard time making my WPF form scrollable. The form is quite long, and i want the user to be able to scroll further down. If i adjust the height of the form, as the scrollbar becomes active, it moves everything around, and makes my content smaller. How do i avoid this? I've added 2 Pictures (Before & After) and my XAML code.

[image]

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="RegisterForm.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="700" MinHeight="1000" MinWidth="700">

<ScrollViewer
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    CanContentScroll="True">





<Grid>


    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>





        <Label
        Content="Full Name"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,40,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </Label>

    <Label
        Content="Gender"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,40,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </Label>

        <Label
        Content="Date of Birth"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,40,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <Label
        Content="Address"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="4"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,40,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </Label>

    <Label
        Content="Phone Number"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="7"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,40,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </Label>

    <Label
        Content="Phone Number Family"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="8"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,0,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </Label>

    <Label
        Content="E-mail"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="9"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,40,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </Label>

    <Label
        Content="Do you speak english?"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="10"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,0,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </Label>

    <Label
        Content="Education"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="11"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,40,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </Label>

    <Label
        Content="Job Type/Profession"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="12"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,0,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </Label>

    <Label
        Content="Experience"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="13"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,40,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </Label>

    <Label
        Content="Drivers License"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Grid.Row="14"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="40,0,40,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    </Label>

    <TextBox
        x:Name="txtFirstName"
        FontSize="14"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,0,0,30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    </TextBox>

        <Label
        Content="First Name"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <TextBox
        x:Name="txtLastName"
        FontSize="14"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="5"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="10,0,0,30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>

        <Label
        Content="Last Name"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="5"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <ComboBox
            x:Name="CBGender"
            FontSize="12"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Margin="10,0,0,30"
            IsEditable="True"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="Please Select"
            FontStyle="Normal">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Male" FontStyle="Normal"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Female" FontStyle="Normal"/>
        </ComboBox>

        <ComboBox
            x:Name="CBDOBDay"
            FontSize="12"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
            Margin="10,0,0,30"
            IsEditable="True"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="DD"
            FontStyle="Normal">
        </ComboBox>

        <ComboBox
            x:Name="CBDOBMonth"
            FontSize="12"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="4"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
            Margin="10,0,0,30"
            IsEditable="True"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="MM"
            FontStyle="Normal">
        </ComboBox>

        <ComboBox
            x:Name="CBDOBYear"
            FontSize="12"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="5"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
            Margin="10,0,0,30"
            IsEditable="True"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="YY"
            FontStyle="Normal">
        </ComboBox>

        <TextBox
        x:Name="txtStreetAddress"
        FontSize="14"
        Grid.Row="4"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="10,0,0,30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>

        <Label
        Content="Street Address"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="4"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <TextBox
        x:Name="txtCity"
        FontSize="14"
        Grid.Row="5"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,0,0,30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>

        <Label
        Content="City"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="5"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <TextBox
        x:Name="txtStateProvince"
        FontSize="14"
        Grid.Row="5"
        Grid.Column="5"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="10,0,0,30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>

        <Label
        Content="State / province"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="5"
        Grid.Column="5"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <TextBox
        x:Name="txtPostalZipCode"
        FontSize="14"
        Grid.Row="6"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,0,0,30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>

        <Label
        Content="Postal / Zip code"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="6"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <ComboBox
            x:Name="CBCountry"
            FontSize="12"
            Grid.Row="6"
            Grid.Column="5"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Margin="10,0,0,30"
            IsEditable="True"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="Please Select"
            FontStyle="Normal" SelectionChanged="CBCountry_SelectionChanged">
        </ComboBox>


        <Label
        Content="Country"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="6"
        Grid.Column="5"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <TextBox
        x:Name="txtPhone1AreaCode"
        FontSize="14"
        Grid.Row="7"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,0,0,30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>

        <TextBox
        x:Name="txtPhone1"
        FontSize="14"
        Grid.Row="7"
        Grid.Column="5"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="10,0,0,30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>

        <Label
        Content="Area Code (ex. +45)"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="7"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <Label
        Content="Phone Number"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="7"
        Grid.Column="5"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <TextBox
        x:Name="txtPhone2AreaCode"
        FontSize="14"
        Grid.Row="8"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,0,0,30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>

        <TextBox
        x:Name="txtPhone2"
        FontSize="14"
        Grid.Row="8"
        Grid.Column="5"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="10,0,0,30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>

        <Label
        Content="Area Code (ex. +45)"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="8"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <Label
        Content="Phone Number"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="8"
        Grid.Column="5"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>

        <TextBox
        x:Name="txtEmail"
        FontSize="14"
        Grid.Row="9"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
        Margin="10,0,0,30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>

        <Label
        Content="Ex. myname@example.com"
        FontSize="12"
        Grid.Row="9"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="10,25,0,0"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </Label>





    </Grid>

</ScrollViewer>
```

//Thanks, Rasmus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with ScrollViewer is that it is virtually infinite. So, the content inside it can't calculate relative sizes such as `*`. In your case, i think if you add a height to your grid, something like `<Grid Height="1000">` it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks alot Pikoh, that solved my problem, guess i didnt have to re-position everything then! Works great now.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the Heigh or MinHeigh of at least one part: The Editors (Labels / Textboxes / Comboboxes) or the GridRows or the whole Grid. Currrently the Grid is filled within the Window and the Columns also fill all together the whole Grid. Normally you would Set Grids' Rows Height to

```
<RowDefinition Height="auto" />
```

instead of

```
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
```

and give the editors some kind of MinHeight or Padding.

So there are many Solutions. It just depends on how you want to have the Labels/Editors Height. (Dynamic or fixed)

**EDIT/ADD:**
And just as a SideNote, if you define the same style foreach of those Row-/ and ColumnDefinitions, you maybe should assign a Style in the Grid for those.
It makes things easier to Change at once ;D

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- ... -->


</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Frerk, i get what you are saying, and i will try that out. I actually tried changing the rows' height to "auto" instead of "*", but it made everything messy, so i quickly gave that up. Guess i will have to re-position everything then.